# Why is (.) called infix as just . rather than `(.)`

Tags: haskell

I learned that functions can be invoked in two ways; prefix and infix. For example, say I've created this function:

```
example :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
example x y = x ++ " " ++ y
```

I can call it prefix like so:

```
example "Hello" "World"
```

or infix like so:

```
"Hello" `example` "World"
```

Both of which will result in the list of chars representing a string `"Hello World"`.

However, I am now learning about function composition, and have come across the function defined like so:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

So, say I was wanting to compose negate with multiplication by three. I would write the prefix invocation like:

```
negateComposedWithMultByThree = (.) negate (*3)
```

And the infix invocation like:

```
negateComposedWithMultByThree = negate `(.)` (*3)
```

But, whilst the prefix invocation compiles, the infix invocation does not and instead gives me the error message:

> error: parse error on input `('

It seems, in order to call compose infix, I need to omit the brackets and call it like so:

```
negateComposedWithMultByThree = negate . (*3)
```

Can anyone shed any light on this? Why does `` "Hello" `example` "World" `` whilst `` negate `(.)` (*3) `` does not?

In addition, if I try to make my own function with a signature like this:

```
(,) :: Int -> Int
(,) x = 1
```

It does not compile, with the error:

> "Invalid type signature (,) : ... Should be of form  :: "

Comment: One can only use these backticks for *varids*, *qvarid*, *conid* and *qconid*s. So variables (qualified or not), and constructors (qualified or not). For operators that is not allowed per Haskell grammar: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html

Comment: But you thus can simply assign `(.)` to a variable, like ``let f = (+) in 2 `f` 3``. The idea is that the brackets `(...)` are more or less the opposite of what it does to an operator, compared to what backticks do to an identifier.

Comment: Ummm, at the risk of sounding stupid, what's a Lexeme?

Comment: I mean, I googled it and it makes sense, but how do I grock it with regards to haskell so I can understand what a qvarid, varid, conid and qconid is?

Comment: a lexeme is a part of your program (like a variable, an operator, etc.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Lexeme

Comment: Ah right it's a token if, like me, you've read bjarnn stroustropps cpp book.

Comment: Hmmm, so (.) is an operator? What exactly does that mean? Does it mean the sequence of characters (.) is reserved at the language level (just like + is in Java for instance). Or does haskell have an entirely different concept of what an operator is?

I found this table of Haskell operators but I cannot see (.) as one of them... https://imada.sdu.dk/~rolf/Edu/DM22/F05/haskell-operatorer.pdf

Comment: I think `(` and `)` are the operators being referred to? Not `.`

Comment: The `Infix-to-prefix constructors` then?

Comment: I’m surprised you tried to call the `.` operator as ``x `(.)` y`` when you didn’t try `++` as ``x `(++)` " " `(++)` y`` or `*` as ``(`(*)` 3)``. Only an alphanumeric name may be wrapped in backticks to change its fixity, and only an operator’s fixity is changed by wrapping it in parens. You can’t mix and match them—but there’s never a need to. Consider these equivalent definitions: `(.) = \f g x -> f (g x)` = `f . g = \x -> f (g x)` = `(f . g) x = f (g x)`, and their parallels with: `com = \f g x -> f (g x)` = ``f `com` g = \x -> f (g x)`` = ``(f `com` g) x = f (g x)`` = `com f g x = f (g x)`

Comment: @bwroga `(` and `)` and *not* operators. they are part of syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's nothing deep here. There's just two kinds of identifiers that have different rules about how they're parsed: by-default-infix, and by-default-prefix. You can tell which is which, because by-default-infix identifiers contain only punctuation, while by-default-prefix identifiers contain only numbers, letters, apostrophes, and underscores.

Recognizing that the default isn't always the right choice, the language provides conversions away from the default behavior. So there are two separate syntax rules, one that converts a by-default-infix identifier to prefix (add parentheses), and one that converts a by-default-prefix identifier to infix (add backticks). You can not nest these conversions: a by-default-infix identifier converted to prefix form is *not* a by-default-prefix identifier.

That's it. Nothing fundamentally interesting -- all of them become just function applications once parsed -- it's just syntax sugar.

Comment: Cool that makes sense, but when you say "the language provides conversions away from the default behaviour" could you elaborate a bit (i.e. give some coded examples?)

Comment: For instance, why does:

```(,) :: Int -> Int
(,) x  = 1```

Not compile?

Comment: @ThomasCook You gave them yourself. `example x y` uses the by-default-prefix behavior, ```x `example` y``` converts from default-prefix to infix; meanwhile `f . g` uses the by-default-infix behavior, `(.) f g` converts from default-infix to prefix.

Comment: @ThomasCook Commas are not valid punctuation for the purpose of defining new by-default-prefix identifiers. You can consult the Report for the full list of valid punctuation.

Comment: Eh?

By the logic:

example x y OR x `example` y

Then it should be:

(.) f g OR f `(.)` g

Surely?

Comment: @ThomasCook No, `.` is a by-default-infix identifier. `(.)` is *not* a by-default-prefix identifier; it is the conversion of a by-default-infix identifier to prefix form.

Comment: Daniel your comment "Commas are not valid punctuation for the purpose of defining new by-default-prefix identifiers" made me go and write a function:

`($) :: a -> a -> a ($) x y = x ++ " " ++ y` which compiled, I was then able to write "Hello" $ "World" and get "Hello World"

It all makes sense now, thanks

Comment: @ThomasCook "For instance, why does: `(,) :: Int -> Int (,) x = 1` Not compile?" You can't use commas, they're reserved. There is also already a built-in constructor `(,)`, which is the prefix form for a two-tuple: `(,) x y == (x, y)`