# How can I find out the type of operator "+"?

Tags: haskell

In GHCi, version 8.6.3 (https://repl.it/languages/haskell), I would like to know how to find out the type of operator "+". I want to see if its type is `num a, b,c => a -> b -> c` or `num a, b,c => (a,b) -> c`.

But I can't find its type out. It also affects the next expression in an unknown way. Why do I fail and what shall I do then?

```
   :type +
   :type not
<interactive>:1:1: error: parse error on input ‘+’
   :type not
not :: Bool -> Bool
=> "12"
```

Answer (score 6):

This way:

```
> :type (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

And also

```
> :t (+) 4
(+) 4 :: Num a => a -> a

> :t (+) 4 3
(+) 4 3 :: Num a => a
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why `()`? Why did mysterious effect of my failed experiment happen?

Comment: You have it answered in your first haskell question, about "sections". It's just syntax. See the comments there.

Comment: [here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56960590/849891). It wasn't your question after all. :)

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to know the type of `+`, not `(+)`.

Comment: @Tim `+` is not a valid expression in Haskell, so it does not have a type.

Comment: @DanielWagner a function has a type. Is `+` a function?

Comment: @Tim No, `+` is not a function. It is not an expression at all, and therefore certainly not an expression whose type has an arrow in it (which is the definition of "function", as far as I am concerned).

Comment: @DanielWagner What is `+`?

Comment: @Tim `+` is an identifier. (I don't see how knowing that will help you, or what you are trying to learn, so I'm afraid I can not expand further than to answer the exact question you ask here.)

Comment: @DanielWagner Thanks. Hutton wrote in his book: "Functions  such  as  +  that  are  written  between  their  two  arguments  are  called  operators." So I guess `+` is a function. In confusion.

Comment: @Tim Advanced users often get sloppy because for them, some thoughts are so automatic that it is not clear how it could be confusing to conflate e.g. the terms "function" and "identifier". I myself in normal converse would call `+` a function, because it is exhausting to draw all these fine distinctions all the time when they're not important... but when you are a beginner, they can be very important for understanding things!

Comment: @DanielWagner in algebra, operator such as + is a function. I don't know why Haskell wants to make things different.

Comment: @Tim I'm going to disagree with you there. If we're being very careful about our definitions, in algebra, `+` is also not a function; it is a piece of syntax which has not yet had its two arguments filled in. I *might* be convinced that, e.g. `3 +` is a function, although I think you would find most mathematicians would prefer to say that it is merely a meaningless string of symbols until it has both arguments. 1/2

Comment: @Tim For an example of why I argue like this: one might say in algebra that if `f` is a function, then `f(x1,x2,x3)` (with an appropriate number of `x`s) is an application of that function. But nobody writes `+(3,4)` -- so what is the distinction there? The answer is that `+` is a different kind of syntax than `f`, both in algebra and in Haskell. 2/2

Comment: @DanielWagner In a group G, its binary operation is a function: G x G -> G. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition. (R, +, 0) is a group. I guess Haskell has some design or implementation consideration, which is beyond my undersanding

Comment: @Tim Again this is advanced users being sloppy about terminology, and nothing more. It is handy to say "`+` is a function" because it is short and all your favorite advanced user friends understand that you actually mean "the operation which maps two arguments `x` and `y` to the value `x+y` is a function" without you having to make all those fine, precise distinctions.

Answer (score 3):

In the Haskell's console, you have to use the `:t` key giving to it a value such as you would use it in your program, some examples:

```
plus = +
```

will give an error

```
plus = (+)
```

it's ok:

```
ghci> :t plus
ghci> :t (+)

Num a => a -> a -> b
```

so:

```
plusOne = + 1
```

will give you an error also

but

```
plusOne  = (+ 1)
plusOne' = (1 +)
```

it's Ok:

```
:t plusOne'
:t plusOne
:t (1 +)
:t (+ 1)

Num a => a -> a
```

and finally:

```
twoPlusOne = 2 + 1

:t twoPlusOne
:t 2 + 1

Num a => b
```